# FE rendering : how to have a custom class on a blockquote tag in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

I've inserted a blockquote tag (twitter quote) in my RTE. 
When saving, everything is ok in the database (....) but not in the frontend.

My tag

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">...
```

is transform to

```
<blockquote style="margin-bottom:10;margin-top:0;">...
```

I used many TS config. The last I used is :

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.blockquote.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.blockquote.overrideAttribs >
```

but it didn't solve it.

Someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.proc.tags {
        blockquote.allowedAttribs = id, class, title, alt
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Page Setup:

```
tt_content.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks.blockquote.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.blockquote.fixAttrib.style.unset=1
```

or place your code beginning with ***lib.parseFunc_RTE.*** in Page Setup